# package does not exist while deploying

Tags: java, heroku, talend

I'm trying to run a Talend job from Java code!
I followed the instructions from https://help.talend.com/reader/Lod~TDRaNw2L2VZKV9XgZw/ty4l9kEdDoVHlHIAOW1e~Q
and it works perfectly when i run it, but i can't deploy it on heroku

my code :

```
package com.example.demo;

import local_project.addcase_0_1.addCase;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    }
}
@RestController
class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String TestJob() {
        addCase a = new addCase();
        a.runJob(new String[] {});   
        return "Added";
    }
}
```

errors while deploying in heroku

```
remote:        [INFO] 3 errors
remote:        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  11.171 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-28T13:19:02Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_555cf666918f4cc22848d177306270f3/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java:[2,33] package local_project.addcase_0_1 does not exist
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_555cf666918f4cc22848d177306270f3/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java:[22,17] cannot find symbol
remote:        [ERROR]   symbol:   class addCase
remote:        [ERROR]   location: class com.example.demo.HelloController
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_555cf666918f4cc22848d177306270f3/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java:[22,33] cannot find symbol
remote:        [ERROR]   symbol:   class addCase
remote:        [ERROR]   location: class com.example.demo.HelloController
remote:        [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to excel-to-case.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/excel-to-case.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/excel-to-case.git'
```

my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testSAV</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testSAV</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>addcase_0_1</groupId>
            <artifactId>addcase_0_1</artifactId>
            <!--  <scope>system</scope> -->
            <version>1.0</version>
            <!--  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/routines.jar</systemPath> -->
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>routines</groupId>
            <artifactId>routines</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/routines.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>











        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>

                 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

the error now is in the import local_project.addcase_0_1.addCase;

heroku logs :

```
2020-05-03T15:37:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/457ad836-1540-41de-9249-bfcbbd84b49b/activity/builds/49b7bd2b-ef75-4406-85e1-70a86abb641c
2020-05-03T15:59:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user mehdi1.chelly1@gmail.com
2020-05-03T15:59:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/457ad836-1540-41de-9249-bfcbbd84b49b/activity/builds/c1e3e0cc-7298-4b04-90e7-8002db7a8f87
2020-05-03T16:03:20.907668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-05-03T16:03:20.976991+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-05-03T16:03:22.085249+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-03 16:03:22.084  INFO 4 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-06T16:29:02.123057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2020-05-06T16:29:02.417880+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-05-06T16:29:08.513593+00:00 app[web.1]: Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
2020-05-06T16:29:08.538367+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2020-05-06T16:29:08.541678+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2020-05-06T16:29:09.835908+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-06T16:29:09.836021+00:00 app[web.1]: .   ____          _            __ _ _
2020-05-06T16:29:09.836101+00:00 app[web.1]: /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2020-05-06T16:29:09.836227+00:00 app[web.1]: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2020-05-06T16:29:09.836307+00:00 app[web.1]: \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2020-05-06T16:29:09.836385+00:00 app[web.1]: '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2020-05-06T16:29:09.836466+00:00 app[web.1]: =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2020-05-06T16:29:09.837993+00:00 app[web.1]: :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)
2020-05-06T16:29:09.838046+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-06T16:29:10.022882+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:10.018  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.example.demo.TestSavApplication      : Starting TestSavApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on c0b428f8-64b5-428d-82c0-8bdce4b7b727 with PID 4 (/app/target/testSAV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by u58099 in /app)
2020-05-06T16:29:10.024061+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:10.023  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.example.demo.TestSavApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-06T16:29:11.171979+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:11.171  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92f6743f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-06T16:29:11.248661+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:11.248  INFO 4 --- [           main] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2020-05-06T16:29:11.610473+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:11.610  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 4317 (http)
2020-05-06T16:29:11.625982+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:11.625  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-06T16:29:11.626341+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:11.626  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:11.705303+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:11.705  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-06T16:29:11.705419+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:11.705  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1591 ms
2020-05-06T16:29:11.948140+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:11.947  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-06T16:29:12.103743+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:12.103  WARN 4 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2020-05-06T16:29:12.333886+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-06T16:29:12.213018+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:12.212  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 4317 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-06T16:29:12.216246+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:12.216  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.example.demo.TestSavApplication      : Started TestSavApplication in 2.936 seconds (JVM running for 3.674)
2020-05-06T16:29:14.643462+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:14.643  INFO 4 --- [nio-4317-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-06T16:29:14.643574+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:14.643  INFO 4 --- [nio-4317-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-06T16:29:14.651667+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:14.651  INFO 4 --- [nio-4317-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 8 ms
2020-05-06T16:29:14.830783+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=excel-to-case.herokuapp.com request_id=04b8f867-b4f7-4817-ab4f-f872d2ed3395 fwd="197.27.207.239" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=220ms status=404 bytes=553 protocol=https
2020-05-06T16:29:15.071769+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=excel-to-case.herokuapp.com request_id=8cf42e29-ed3d-4cbe-a48d-bd26970e7146 fwd="197.27.207.239" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=95ms status=404 bytes=365 protocol=https
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120185+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-05-06 16:29:22.119 ERROR 4 --- [nio-4317-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: local_project/addcase_0_1/addCase] with root cause2020-05-06T16:29:22.120195+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120196+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: local_project.addcase_0_1.addCase
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120197+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_252-heroku]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120197+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_252-heroku]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120198+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:92) ~[testSAV-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120198+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[na:1.8.0_252-heroku]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120199+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.example.demo.ExcelToCase2.TestJob(TestSavApplication.java:42) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120199+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_252-heroku]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120200+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_252-heroku]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120201+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_252-heroku]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120201+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_252-heroku]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120201+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120202+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120204+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120204+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]2020-05-06T16:29:22.120205+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120205+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120206+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120209+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120209+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120209+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120210+00:00 app[web.1]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120210+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120211+00:00 app[web.1]: at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120211+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120212+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120212+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120212+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120213+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120213+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120221+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120222+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120222+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120223+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120223+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120223+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120224+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120224+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120225+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.5.RELEASE]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120225+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120225+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120226+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120226+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120226+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120227+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120227+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120228+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120228+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120228+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120229+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120229+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120230+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120230+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120230+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120231+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_252-heroku]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120231+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_252-heroku]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120232+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar!/:9.0.33]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120232+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252-heroku]
2020-05-06T16:29:22.120233+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-05-06T16:29:22.130526+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/test" host=excel-to-case.herokuapp.com request_id=b92e7552-ab53-43b9-9b71-80d1b597fd0e fwd="197.27.207.239" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=21ms status=500 bytes=489 protocol=https
```

Comment: Do you build your project using Maven locally? The linked instructions seem to explain how to run this within Eclipse itself.

Comment: yes I build it using maven locally. I followed the linked instructions to run my spring-boot project with netbeans. do you have any idea? why it works without any error locally but i cant deploy it ? thanx for your answer

Comment: It looks like your Maven setup does not include all the files that are required to build your project. Can you confirm that `mvn clean install` for this project works on your machine?

Comment: @Malax mvn clean install display the same error, the class is unreachable!

Comment: That's great, so we can reproduce that issue on your local machine too. I assumed it wasn't a Heroku specific issue, but wanted to confirm. This should make it easier to debug what's wrong.

Without seeing your pom it will be hard to guess what's causing this though. Can you provide more info?

Comment: @Malax The problem is that I am using a jar generated by Talend in my Spring boot project, and I am calling a class in my code from this jar. I don't have problems when i run my project locally but when i deploy it the class is not found.

Comment: I fixed the problem, now i can deploy my code but when i call it a 500 error is displayed! the problem is in the import from which I am calling my class

Comment: I Edited my post, u can see my pom

Comment: Can you post the log output (`heroku logs`) when you hit the HTTP 500?

Comment: @Malax Done, I edited my post again

Comment: @Malax any idea ?